# How can I use model to print my data in view with angular 5 using class or interface?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to print my data returning by my backend , and I've created a class to assign to the data :

URI to get User by id return data like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76BSY.jpg

and URI to get all Users return data like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aetm.jpg

I have this 2 functions in my service:

```
    getUserProfile(id): Promise<void | UserProfile> {
        let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/' + id;
        let token2 = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token2);
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this.http.get(url, options)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json().result as UserProfile)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }


  getUserProfileS(sort = '-createdAt'): Promise<void | UserProfile[]> {
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/'
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as UserProfile[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And in my component i have the next :

```
 usuario:UserProfile;

 this._ups.getUserProfile(id).then((user:UserProfile)=>{
     alert("USUARIO"+JSON.stringify(user));
     console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
     this.usuario=user;
     console.log(this.usuario.city);
   }).catch(err=>{
     console.log("ERROR"+err);
   })
```

The problem is that when i print in my view

```
 <h1>{{usuario.name}}</h1>
```

It doesnt exist and i dont know where is the error in my code. 
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Another thing is dont know if should i use interfaces or class ?

my class is the next :

```
 export class UserProfile {
  id: number;
  photoProfile?: any;
  id_facebook?: any;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  country_code: string;
  telephone: string;
  city: string;
  birth: number;
  photo_profile?: any;
  gender: string;
  who_is?: any;
  roles?: any;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using RxJS Observables?

Comment: @Cory Kleiser really I dont know how can i use that with RxJS Observables, could you tell me how can i refactor this ?

Comment: I’d recommend doing the [Angular tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial). That will give you a good start with Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested I've done some refactoring of your code to use RxJS Observables instead of Promises. I haven't tested it so if any errors are logged out just follow the instructions there. Also I'm not handling errors here since that is pretty easy with Observables. It should be a good exercise for you as well. Here is how you would do this using observables:

Service that will return a RxJS Observable instead of promise:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { UserProfile } from 'USER_PROFILE_PATH';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
URL_SERVICIOS = YOUR_URL_HERE;


constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
) { }


getUserProfile(id): Observable<UserProfile> {
    const url = `${URL_SERVICIOS}/users/${id}`;
    const token2 = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token2}`);
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(url, options);
}
```

Your component that will accept the observable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UserProfile } from 'USER_PROFILE_PATH';
import { UserService } from 'USER_SERVICE_PATH';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  usuario: UserProfile;

  id = SOME_ID_HERE;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }


  getUserProfile(): void {
    this.userService.getUserProfile()
        .subscribe(user => this.usuario = user);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserProfile(this.id);
  }

}
```

Comment: i've implement your code in my project and function well but i still have the error when print usuario.name , it says is undefined and if i print usuario print [object Object] , how can i solved this ?

Comment: in services I've changed this :return this.http.get(url,options)
      .map(res => {return res.json().result})
      .catch((e: any) => Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(e)));

Comment: Can you log the object to the console and see what it is?

Comment: When i print it in my component : i get this  :  [link]https://imgur.com/a/uQpFTwl

Comment: I've solved [Object Object] writing this :   usuario = {} as UserProfile; in my component

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `promise` and not `observables` which I prefer,

In your service return `promise` itself,

```
getUserProfile(id): Promise<void | UserProfile> {
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/' + id;
    let token2 = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token2);
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(url, options).toPromise()
}
```

Then you can use `then` in the component and use `user.result`

Use, `this.usuario = user.result;` instead if `this.usuario=user;`

```
this._ups.getUserProfile(id).then((user:UserProfile)=>{
     alert("USUARIO"+JSON.stringify(user));
     console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
     this.usuario=user.result;
     console.log(this.usuario.city);
   }).catch(err=>{
     console.log("ERROR"+err);
   })
```

[**Here is some documentation and example**](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/)

Comment: @JossephBot, have you checked this? any help needed?

Comment: I've tried with your code but i can access to usuario.name , it says is undefined and when i print usuario in my html say  :  [object Object]

Comment: can you `console.log(user)` in response

Comment: take,  `this.usuario= JSON.parse(user._body);` or    `this.usuario= user._body;`

Comment: I've solved [Object Object] writing this :   usuario = {} as UserProfile; in my component